# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: api, google-app-engine, youtube, flask

I am building a web application using Flask and Google App Engine. One of the pages in this web application makes a call via YouTube APIs to get videos given a search term.

I get the following error when I try to query `YoutubeVids.html`.

This only happens when when I pass a certain parameter via Jinja2 templates to the page.

```
file "/Users/xxxxx/App-Engine/src/templates/YoutubeVids.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "master.html" %}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

INFO     2014-01-27 22:39:40,963 module.py:612] default: "GET /xxx/yyyy HTTP/1.1" 500 291
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Figured it out.

I put the following at the start of my python file

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: Or you can use: from __future__ import unicode_literals at the start.

Comment: No... don't... why would you do that?

Comment: @Matt Nordhoff: Why not? I've been doing that forever (and the above give an error).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: See [Dangers of sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657010/dangers-of-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8)

Comment: @idbrii: Yes. It seems there's no way to win (except perhaps Python 3?)!

Comment: What is the default encoding?

Answer (score 12):

From the docs: Jinja2 is using Unicode internally which means that you have to pass Unicode objects to the render function or bytestrings that only consist of ASCII characters.

A normal string in Python 2.x is a bytestring. To make it unicode use:

```
byte_string = 'a Python string which contains non-ascii data like €äãü'
unicode_string = byte_string.decode('utf-8')
```

More: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Comment: Also, [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder, [Flask's Unicode docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/unicode/) and [Jinja's Unicode docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#unicode).